# Complex Number Geometry 5

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let S be the set of complex numbers z such that the real part of 1/z is equal to 1/6. This set forms a curve. Find the area of the region inside the curve.

Can someone explain this problem to me?

Comment: What part of the problem do you find difficult to understand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=a+bi$. Then we have that $$\frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{a+bi} = \frac{a-bi}{(a+bi)(a-bi)}= \frac{a}{a^2+b^2} - \frac{b}{a^2+b^2}i$$ The real part is equal to $1/6$, so we have $$\frac{a}{a^2+b^2} = \frac{1}{6}$$ Plot this on a a-b plane and you'll get a nice circle. The area is what you're looking for. $$\frac{a}{a^2+b^2} = \frac{1}{6} \Rightarrow a^2+b^2=6a \\ \Rightarrow (a-3)^2+b^2=3^2$$ This is a circle with radius $3$, thus the area is simply $\pi (3)^2 = 9\pi$.

Comment: Thanks a lot I get it now :)

Comment: You're welcome, I added the complete solution btw, just in case :)